# Javascript setHours have unexpected behaviour for UTC+2 timezones

Tags: javascript

I have following javascript function

```
function DateIncrement(_Date,_Inc)
{
    return (new Date((new Date(_Date)).setHours(_Inc*24,0,0,0)))
}
```

The purpose is to increment _Date by _Inc days.
This works fine for all the timezone except **UTC+2** time zones **(Amman, Cairo, Beirut etc.)**
For **UTC+2** time zones it does not return next day. It set hours in _Date to 24.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: I guess he wants to know how to make it work for UTC+2 timezones. By the way, time data gets lost this way...

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to increment a JS Date by *n* days, why don't you use `setDate()`?

```
function DateIncrement(_Date,_Inc)
{
    var date = new Date(_Date);
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + _Inc);
    return date;
}
```

... if you really need to set it to midnight, *then* use `setHours()` afterwards.

Comment: I have tried ur code also. It gives same problem.
the problem is for UTC+2 timezone only for date 'Thu Mar 31 00:00:00 UTC+0200 2011'.
The function returns 'Thu Mar 31 23:00:00 UTC+0200 2011' instead of 'Thu Apr 1 00:00:00 UTC+0200 2011'.
Why is this happening?
how to solve this?

Comment: @Rahul Chitale: Not on my computer, how are you creating and outputting the dates?  Have you tried different browsers?